# Hide the close "X" button in Fancybox

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I am using this http://fancybox.net/

Is there a way to add a property to not show the close "X" button on
top right? I mean I can use 'callbackOnShow' to hide it in a hide()
but that is not fast enough. I want it NOT rendered out instead of
rendered then hide.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation at http://fancybox.net/api it cites an option of `showCloseButton` that should do the trick.

From the site:

> showCloseButton - Option to show/hide close button

Comment: I would use the 'closeBtn' option, it seems the above is an old option

Comment: The fancybox.net website is misleading as it contains the documentation for fancybox 1.x but the download link links to fancybox 2, so presumably this will be the right answer if version 1 is what you are using. Documentation for fancybox 2.x is here: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs (@Yogesh's answer worked for me, its also matches up with the docs for v2, this had me confused for a while!)

Answer (score 51):

Looks like `showCloseButton` doesn't work any more. After looking into the fancybox code i figured out `closeBtn` should be set to false.

So in order to hide close button one should add below line in options -

`'closeBtn' : false`

Answer (score 2):

In fancybox 3 use 'modal' e.g.

```
        $.fancybox.open({
            ...
            opts: {
                modal: true,
            }
        });
```

Comment: True for Jul 2019

Answer (score 2):

For those who are looking for disable it completely in fancybox v3, here it is:

```
smallBtn: false,
toolbar: false
```

Answer (score 0):

use boolean in 'showCloseButton' attribute. e.g

```
$('.editGnBtn').fancybox({
   'href': "#editGn",
   'showCloseButton':false
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following in ...
`.fancybox-close {display:none; }`

But it is advisable only if the same **fancybox** is a popup which will automatically disappear after some time (using `$.fancybox.close();`)

Answer (score -1):

Try it, to never close the windows in fancybox v4:

```
Fancybox.show(gallery, {
    Toolbar: {
        display: [
            { id: "counter", position: "center" },
            "fullscreen",
        ],
    },
    'closeButton': '',
    'infinite': false,
    'click': 'next',
    'dragToClose': false,
    keyboard: {
        Escape: "false",
        Delete: "false",
        Backspace: "false",
        PageUp: "next",
        PageDown: "prev",
        ArrowUp: "next",
        ArrowDown: "prev",
        ArrowRight: "next",
        ArrowLeft: "prev",
    }
});
```