# How to delete the (X) at the top right side of fancy box

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is it ok if I just "display:none" the cross (X) of fancybox to hide it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739669/hide-the-close-x-button-in-fancybox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When calling fancybox, add the following option:

```
'showCloseButton':false
```

For instance:

```
$('#your_id').fancybox({'showCloseButton':false});
```

Comment: @Quasdunk: Yes, I tried already but I just want to see if its ok and wont cause other problems.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
'closeBtn':false
```

to hide the close button.